# Update url/folder structure

Tags: php, zend-framework2

We currently have some pages/urls like this:

```
www.aaa.com/somecontroller/someaction
www.aaa.com/someothercontroller/someotheraction
...
```

I have to keep the same pages but the urls has to look like this (everything has to be under 'redesign' folder)

```
www.aaa.com/redesign/somecontroller/someaction
www.aaa.com/redesign/someothercontroller/someotheraction
...
```

I am not very familiar with ZF. Do I have to actually create a sub folder 'redesign'? Or do I make some changes to the routes in module.config.php? or both?

Thanks

Comment: What web server? You can set a configuration to point all that traffic without moving anything.

Comment: It's apache server, but prefer to do it in code. (It will take a few weeks if I request for any changes to the server)

Comment: Code just is not the correct way to do it. You want to use Apache rewrite rules. You can use .htaccess files in the mean time while you wait for your server guys to implement your rewrites permanently.

Comment: Are you wanting to move your whole application into the 'redesign' folder, or just some of its URLs?

Comment: The whole application. I would like all the urls to be under /redesign.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ZF project called **redesign** and in the parent folder (when you have www.aaa.com) you have for example a WordPress CMS I suggested to make a folder manually inside your hosting.

www/var/wp-content

www/var/wp-includes

www/var/wp-admin

...

www/var/**redesign**

Good luck!